# Forward Fourier Transfrom

Tags: sentinel-2

When executing a Forward Fourier Transform on a sentinel 2 image (and changing the color table) the blue (B2), green (B3), red (B4), produces similar results but near-infrared (B8) has very clear horizontal and vertical information. Why is this? and Why is the information off-center? Does it matter?

| B2 (blue) | B8 (nir) |
| --- | --- |
| [image: First] | [image: row] |